# LibreOffice Math Subscript ? Bug

Tags: linux, libreoffice

When using libreoffice on linux you cannot type

```
V sub in
```

in the math editor and actually get in.  In place is a question mark as if I had typed

```
V sub ?
```

How to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by typing "in" after sub. "" removes calling a function